# Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm doing a call via POSTMAN to my POST method that should return a String type, but when I'm doing the call it's giving me the error `"Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java. lang.String out of START_OBJECT token"`. Why is this happening?

**Attribute in the entity:**

```java
@Column(name = "CIF_NIF")
@JsonView(Views.Buscador.class)
@JsonProperty("cifNif")
private String cifNif;
```

**RestController**:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/recuperaNombreLegalCliente")
public String recuperaNombreLegalCliente(@RequestBody String cifNif) {
  return contratoService.getNombreLegalCliente(cifNif);
}
```

**Repository**

```java
@Query(value="SELECT c.nombreSociedadPersona FROM Contrato c WHERE c.cifNif= ?1")
public String getNombreLegalCliente(String cifNif);
```

**The input when I'm doing the method call:**

```java
{
    "cifNif": "E85882355"
}
```

***EDIT 1 Stack trace error now (after @sigur answer)***

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [Contrato [id=null, tipoSolicitud=null, tipoContratoDiscriminator=null, cifNif=E85882355] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Contrato [id=null, tipoSolicitud=null, tipoContratoDiscriminator=null, cifNif=E85882355] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.getNombreLegalCliente(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.xxxx.servicio.ContratoService.getNombreLegalCliente(ContratoService.java:24)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.acciones.rest.SolicitudAutorizacionPreciosRestController.recuperaNombreLegalCliente(SolicitudAutorizacionPreciosRestController.java:56)
```

Comment: updated the answer but if you need more support you should open another question because the original one looks like it has been resolved @okjfokjrf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapper for the `@RequestBody` is trying to read your input and transform its data for the requested type/object.

In your case it's trying to transform your json text into `String`. This is not allowed by default, you should change your input in POJO class which reflects the model of the json input.

Change `public String recuperaNombreLegalCliente(@RequestBody String cifNif)` to something like `String recuperaNombreLegalCliente(@RequestBody Cliente cifNif)`, where `Cliente` is a class like:

```
 class Cliente {
   private String cifNif;

  public void setCifNif(String cifNif) {this.cifNif = cifNif;}
  public String getCifNif() {return cifNif;}
 }
```

---

**case edit 1 -> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException**

The error is related to the query generation into your repository. When you changed your `String` into the `Cliente` class, you need also to adequate your call for your repository, or the query; because now you are trying to map a `Cliente` instance as a parameter into your query for a string field/column.

If you want to use the `Cliente` you need to use the `cifNif` property into your query. Example:

```
@Query(value="SELECT c.nombreSociedadPersona FROM Contrato c WHERE c.cifNif=cliente.cifNif")
public String getNombreLegalCliente(@Param("cliente") Cliente cliente);
...
```

Or if you want to use the string value just callthe repository function from your controller:

```
String recuperaNombreLegalCliente(@RequestBody Cliente cifNif) {
 repository.getNombreLegalCliente(cifNif.getCifNif());
...
}
```

where the repository method is:

```
@Query(value="SELECT c.nombreSociedadPersona FROM Contrato c WHERE c.cifNif= ?1")
public String getNombreLegalCliente(String cifNif);
...
```

Comment: Then i should put something like "cliente" : { "cifNif" : "xxxx" } ?

Comment: Request is going to be the same, but when the mapper is going to reflect its data into your model it uses the getters and setters POJO style. So when the request {"cifNif": "E85882355"} is going to "enter" into your controller the mapper and the @RequestBody are going to transform into into Cliente. They extract the fields from your json (in your case only cifNif) and are going to find them into the Cliente class (by a 'pojo setter' style -> setCiNif).

Comment: not working for me like that with the same input and with your change Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Contrato [id=null, tipoSolicitud=null, tipoContratoDiscriminator=null, cifNif=E85882355]

Comment: You should add the stacktrace for the case, because I suspect the error is not anymore "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token" so it has been changed, because now it looks like you got next steps further than the previous.

Comment: Yeah it's not the same error, i'm adding the strack trace error in the question

Comment: @okjfokjrf did this answer help you? Could you accept in case, thanks